# Como puedo depurar mi código python

Tags: python, sublimetext3, depuración

Estoy empezando en la programación y se me hace muy complicado depurar código para encontrar que es lo que no funciona en mi programa.

Recuerdo que en Dev-C++ era super sencillo, tenía una herramienta de debugging que te decía el valor de cada variable y cómo cambiaba con cada línea. Pero ahora que estoy aprendiendo python, uso [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) y las formas de depurar que encuentro no me dan esa información y no las entiendo.

No sabéis ninguna forma de depurar python que sea noob friendly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque no soy familiar con este para desarrollar en python, SublimeText3 tiene múltiples potenciales extensiones. [Este plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Debugger) parece más o menos lo que buscas, con su panel de variables y no es complejo de usar.

Si no te importa cambiar de entorno, [Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) es un IDE bastante completo con edición community gratuita. Es algo pesado, dependiendo de la capacidad de tu equipo, pero trae bastantes funcionalidades útiles, entre ellas el típico depurador.

Comment: @Ismael spanish please. :)